# How can I automatically open a certain website page in Google sheets based on a condition?

Tags: if-statement, url, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is the problem I don't know how to fix. 
If the value in cell A2 > 0 then open the copied URL in cell A3. 
Is there an easy script that I can use to launch a new value-based website? 
Any support will be much appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

try simple `IF`

```
=IF(A2 > 0; "https://stackoverflow.com/a/60959851/5632629"; )
```

---

> in cell A2 I have a value, in cell B2 I have the URL(ex."https:/www.google.com/), "and in cell C2 the condition for opening the website from B2 if the value is A2 > 0.

```
=IF(A2>C2, "https://www.google.com/", )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you player0, but your solution doesn't work, it doesn't open the desired web page.

Comment: I can't paste the screenshot here, but here's a more detailed description if it helps, in cell A2 I have a value, in cell B2 I have the URL(ex."https:/www.google.com/), "and in cell C2 the condition for opening the website from B2 if the value is A2 > 0. I hope it helps.